# How to use two different Struct Models with name collisions

Tags: swift, model, namespaces

In my Swift app (ios 16/xcode 14), I call two different National Weather Service APIs and use JSONDecoder to decode the results.

```
if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AlertModel.self, from: data) {

if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ForecastModel.self, from: data) {
```

AlertModel:

```
//
// This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let alert = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Alert.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

// MARK: - Alert
struct AlertModel: Codable {
    let context: [ContextElement]
    let type: String
    let features: [Feature]
    let title: String
    let updated: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case context = "@context"
        case type, features, title, updated
    }
}

enum ContextElement: Codable {
    case contextClass(ContextClass)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(ContextClass.self) {
            self = .contextClass(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(ContextElement.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for ContextElement"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .contextClass(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - ContextClass
struct ContextClass: Codable {
    let version: String
    let wx, vocab: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case version = "@version"
        case wx
        case vocab = "@vocab"
    }
}

// MARK: - Feature
struct Feature: Codable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let geometry: JSONNull?
    let properties: Properties
}

// MARK: - Properties
struct Properties: Codable {
    let id: String
    let type, propertiesID, areaDesc: String
    let geocode: Geocode
    let affectedZones: [String]
    let references: [Reference]
    let sent, effective, onset, expires: String
    let ends: String
    let status, messageType, category, severity: String
    let certainty, urgency, event, sender: String
    let senderName, headline, description, instruction: String
    let response: String
    let parameters: Parameters

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "@id"
        case type = "@type"
        case propertiesID = "id"
        case areaDesc, geocode, affectedZones, references, sent, effective, onset, expires, ends, status, messageType, category, severity, certainty, urgency, event, sender, senderName, headline, description, instruction, response, parameters
    }
}

// MARK: - Geocode
struct Geocode: Codable {
    let same, ugc: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case same = "SAME"
        case ugc = "UGC"
    }
}

// MARK: - Parameters
struct Parameters: Codable {
    let awipSidentifier, wmOidentifier, nwSheadline, blockchannel: [String]
    let vtec: [String]
    let eventEndingTime: [String]
    let easOrg, expiredReferences: [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case awipSidentifier = "AWIPSidentifier"
        case wmOidentifier = "WMOidentifier"
        case nwSheadline = "NWSheadline"
        case blockchannel = "BLOCKCHANNEL"
        case vtec = "VTEC"
        case eventEndingTime
        case easOrg = "EAS-ORG"
        case expiredReferences
    }
}

// MARK: - Reference
struct Reference: Codable {
    let id: String
    let identifier, sender: String
    let sent: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "@id"
        case identifier, sender, sent
    }
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // No-op
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

ForecastModel:

```
 / This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let forecastModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ForecastModel.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation


// MARK: - ForecastModel
struct ForecastModel: Codable {
    let context: [ContextElement]
    let type: String
    let geometry: Geometry
    let properties: Properties

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case context = "@context"
        case type, geometry, properties
    }
}

enum ContextElement: Codable {
    case contextClass(ContextClass)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(ContextClass.self) {
            self = .contextClass(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(ContextElement.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for ContextElement"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .contextClass(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
//
// MARK: - ContextClass
struct ContextClass: Codable {
    let version: String
    let wx: String
    let geo, unit: String
    let vocab: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case version = "@version"
        case wx, geo, unit
        case vocab = "@vocab"
    }
}

// MARK: - Geometry
struct Geometry: Codable {
    let type: String
    let coordinates: [[[Double]]]
}

//// MARK: - Properties
struct Properties: Codable {
    //let updated: Date
    let updated: String
    let units, forecastGenerator: String
    //let generatedAt, updateTime: Date
    let generatedAt, updateTime: String
    let validTimes: String
    let elevation: Elevation
    let periods: [Period]
}

//// MARK: - Elevation
struct Elevation: Codable {
    let unitCode: String
    let value: Double
}

//// MARK: - Period
struct Period: Codable {
    let number: Int
    let name: String
    //let startTime, endTime: Date
    let startTime, endTime: String
    let isDaytime: Bool
    let temperature: Int
    let temperatureUnit: TemperatureUnit
    let temperatureTrend: JSONNull?
    let windSpeed, windDirection: String
    let icon: String
    let shortForecast, detailedForecast: String
}

enum TemperatureUnit: String, Codable {
    case f = "F"
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // No-op
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

As you can see there are name collisions between models. Both api's work fine with the other model commented out. How can I use some sort of name space trick to make these two models play nice together?

Comment: Could you not move the ContextElement at the scope of AlertModel/ForecastModel ?

Comment: Use nested structs.

Comment: You can name your models whatever you want so why does they have to have the same names to start with?

Comment: @Joakim, They do not have the same name. One is ForecastModel.swift and the other is AlertsModel.swift. There are compile errors when both are un-commented.

Comment: @Petar, The first thing I did was to was comment out structs and enums in one file but not the other. This allows them both to compile but then JSONDecoder fails. One main issue is they both have same names but different content such as Properties struct. SAme name but different content.

Comment: @HangarRash, Can you explain what that means?

Comment: I was of course talking about the sub types, not sure how you managed to misunderstand that.

Comment: @Tim What HangarRash said is the same as what I said - you could have ContextElement added at the scope of the AlertModel  struct AlertModel: Codable { struct ContextElement { } ... } . This way your type will be AlertModel.ContextElement - https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/nestedtypes/

Comment: Got it to work by nesting all model data in ForecastModel/AlertModel Struct. I still see these ghost errors about ForecastModel and AlertModel being redeclared but they go away and it runs....Thanks for all of your help! P.S. Not sure why someone down voted the question.

Comment: @Tim You have added way more code to your question than is necessary to understand the problem. Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and please edit accordingly. Also I moved my comment above as an answer so if you're happy you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have `ContextElement` added at the scope of the `AlertModel` like

```
struct AlertModel: Codable { 
   struct ContextElement { ... } 
   ... 
}
```

This way your type will be e.g. `AlertModel.ContextElement`. Read more about [nested types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/nestedtypes/).